# Reset search field or use backspace character to reset field (CasperJS)

Tags: javascript, casperjs, reset

I am writing in Casper Javacript and I am writing a test for a search bar object that tests each letter of the alphabet, by itself. So it will test 'a' then 'b' and so on. I am using the sendKeys function to send the keystroke of the letter. The problem is that it concatinates the letters even when I don't want it to, this is important part of my code. So the first loop will do a in the field, the second does ab, third abc, fourth abcd.

```
var alph = ['a','b','c','d'];
var c = alph[z]; 
this.sendKeys('.et_searchbar_wide', c , {reset: true});
```

I either want to reset if properly, which the "reset: true" should do (I thought). Or just enter a backspace key before I enter a new letter every time, which would be fine. Either one would solve the problem. But I cannot seem to find a solution anywhere online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for an hour and finally deciding to make a post, i find it in my next search, for anyone interested i just used '\b' + c in my sendKeys and that worked just fine.